# How do you rename a folder/directory in your project solution in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I feel like this should be extremely straightforward and I'm not finding the options.

Every time I add a new folder to the solution it just creates it with the name "NewFolder" and I can't see an option to rename it.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer. I believe Visual Studio prevents you from renaming a folder until you build the solution (for .NET). I built the solution and then was given the option to rename after right-clicking the folder...

Comment: Do you see the blue background ?I renaming it on the blue background, and I don't need to buid the solution.https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm9IP.gif